# How to detect ios numberpad delete press

Tags: ios, numpad

dose anyone know how to detect a delete press from a numberpad in ios?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a UITextField, your delegate's `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` will be called with a range of length 1 and an empty replacement string. If nothing is deleted, however, you will get no notification.

If you're using a UITextView, your delegate's `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` will be called with a range of length 1 and an empty replacement string. If nothing is deleted, however, you will get no notification.

If you're using your own class that implements UIKeyInput, `deleteBackward` is supposed to be called. I don't know whether a class implementing UITextInput (which itself includes UIKeyInput) might ever have `replaceRange:withText:` or `setMarkedText:selectedRange:` called instead with a range of length 1 and an empty replacement string, or what might happen in those cases if there is nothing to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing something like a passcode, I think a hidden textfield would be preferable, and more controls.

Comment: Please expand on thsi answer.  Why for instance.